# Map in map storing

Tags: javascript, dictionary

how can I store map in map in javascript?

```
var data = {};
data['key'] = {'val1', 'val2'};
```

And I get an error about wrong id.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You either need an array...

```
var data = {};
data['key'] = ['val1', 'val2'];  // store an Array at data.key

data.key[0]; // 'val1'
```

...or keys for your values in the object...

```
var data = {};
data['key'] = {key1:'val1', key2:'val2'};  // store an Object at data.key 

data.key.key1;  // 'val1'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want just an array (a list) in the `data` map, what patrick dw has is fine.

If you want a map in your `data` map, you need the following:

```
var data = {};
data['key'] = {'val1': 'val2'}; // using a colon instead of a comma to create key-value pairing
```

You can also simplify this using JavaScript object notation:

```
var data = {};
data.key = {val1: 'val2'};
```